# How to replace corrupt Git objects with new ones created from my files, which are fine

Tags: git

My app, in my filesystem, works just fine. All tests pass.

I'm a sole developer, using Git mostly to use Heroku as well as for backup.

Git has stopped working because of corrupt objects.

I'm getting errors that look like this:

```
steven-nobles-imac-200:drominay steven$ git push heroku master
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
fatal: object 990ad2766afa2e2002eea265225ad160e73eacd2 is corrupted
error: pack-objects died with strange error
```

(And many other errors, all citing corrupted objects.)

How do I get Git to throw out the corrupt objects and replace them with new objects built from the working copy of my app?

`Git init` didn't solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `git-fsck`.  The manual has [details](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#recovering-from-repository-corruption), but the gist is that git-fsck will make sure that the repository is internally consistent and list the missing objects, then you may use `git hash-object -w <correct-file>` to put the file given into the repository.  If the file given to hash-object really is the one that was corrupt, your repository is now complete again :).

Updated to add: [Git repair](http://git-repair.branchable.com/) does the same things, but automagically :).

Comment: But that doesn't work if the object in question is in a pack, right? How would I tell git to use the recovered object and not the one in the pack file?

Comment: @FrederickNord, the best option now (and I've edited my answer accordingly) is to use Joey Hess's git-repair.