# Git corrupted with a commit

Tags: git

I am a bit new to git but I read the Git book from their site.
So I started to use one with GitLab installed on my server.

I was working on SVN before so the first commit was an export of SVN.
My friend is also working on the same project (his name's Lucas).

I created a branch *origin/dev* to get the *origin/master* fully stable and then develop on /dev.
I also created a branch *feature258* I'm working on. When I tried to pull the *origin/dev* to fetch the changes before merging my great feature I have this :

```
$ git pull origin dev
fatal: object 18c29b4c26d7b0d34719d10ada6901c6024f91e6 is corrupted
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It appears that the *18c29b4* object is the *pink* commit (cf ScreenShot) which only modify a bit the .gitignore file

I ran *git fsck --full* but the clue that I'm having didn't help me :

```
$ git fsck --full
dangling blob 0c87d2eb401651ec3045eb0248d54ed546206dbe
dangling blob 1cd17aadc009ba9d39d1137533d65107ca54da95
```

The blob 0c and 1c are only one file that I modified in my last commit in feature_258.

I search over 3 hours on Google finding Linus Torvalds method and other StackOverflow posts without finding a good solution.

If it can save me, maybe I can rebase on branch before the BAD commit and re-do my work (that I saved in another directory to be sure)

[image: Screenshot of SourceTree]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace corrupt Git objects with new ones created from my files, which are fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183780/how-to-replace-corrupt-git-objects-with-new-ones-created-from-my-files-which-ar)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. I have done : git hash-object -w 'the-file-from-fsck' and it tells me that :
`95e1180c100930f579854d1fd03f2585eb7e5dc7`
So what I'm supposed to do with ? Thank you for your previous answer !

Comment: The corrupted object is on the `origin`, not in your repository. You have to run `git fsck --full` there

Comment: So I'm on my server, located in : $GITOLITE/repositories/my_repo.git/ and doing `git fsck --full` and nothing is printed ...

Answer (score 1):

Usually this:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Tells about connection termination. Maybe(maybe) this is not a Git repo problem, but some sort of system trouble. If I were you, I'd started with checking file permissions in repo. If you're using gitolite, then it'll be something like:

```
chown git:git -R $GITOLITE/repositories/my_repo.git/
chmod u+rw -R $GITOLITE/repositories/my_repo.git/
```

Then, if its not an issue, i'd tried to clone repo *on server*:

```
git clone $GITOLITE/repositories/my_repo.git/ ~/test_clone.git
```

Also there's one more suggestion - log in as user **git** and check git version.