# How to download a specific folder of Chromium code?

Tags: git, github, browser, download, chromium

Recently, I tried to download source code for chromium browser. In details, I just wanted to download code at https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/chrome. I tried several methods such as Downgit and SVN but nothing worked. The thing is, the methods I used worked on other sites and folders. I can't understand. Could anyone help me? If not, please let me know any other place where I can download desktop version chromium browser source code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not how it works. The Chromium source code includes source code for all the major operating systems and most of the codes are shared too. Just follow the instructions specified in the guidelines

Comment: I don't want to download full source nor build it. I just want to check out some codes in chromium browser source code. I saw guidelines and found nothing proper for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this question when I was looking for the same thing and as it turns out @VonC's solution is almost right. You do

```
git clone \
--depth 1 \
--filter=blob:none \
--no-checkout \
https://github.com/chromium/chromium \
;
cd chromium
```

but before you checkout you just set `core.fscache = false` via the

```
git config core.fscache false
```

command
and then continue with

```
 git sparse-checkout init --cone
 git sparse-checkout set chrome
```

The sha1 error is not your fault and is just a bug with git, in another similar post an issue was opened about it and this fscache was the solution they gave for the time being. If you're on Linux you don't even have to do this. The commands mentioned above would work! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to download full source nor build it. I just want to check out some codes in chromium browser source code

Since it is a Git repository, you can use a [filter clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/6309) (I [detail its syntax here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309)):

```bash
git clone \
  --depth 1 \
  --filter=blob:none \
  --no-checkout \
  https://github.com/chromium/chromium \
;
cd chromium
git switch main -- chrome
```

You also have the [sparse cone option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526704/6309):

```bash
git clone \
  --depth 1 \
  --filter=blob:none \
  --no-checkout \
  https://github.com/chromium/chromium \
;
cd chromium
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout set chrome
git switch main
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both of them but nothing seems to work. The first one causes sha1 error and the second one does not change anything.

Comment: @Rapunzel What Git vrsion are you using? On which OS?

Comment: Git 2.28 on windows 10 1909

Comment: @Rapunzel OK, so at least that is not because of an old version of Git.

Comment: I think so. I think it has something to do with the remote repository.

Comment: chromium's master branch was renamed to main. `git sparse-checkout` is faster. the `git sparse-checkout` code is missing a `git checkout main` (this is the slowest part, it takes about 8 minutes on the chromium repo)

Comment: @milahu Thank you for this feedback: I have edited the answer accordingly.